# WPF Height Databinding question

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have an ScrollViewer that I am trying to do data binding on the height of.  The ScrollViewer holds a long ListBox

So here is my question.  My ScrollViewer will bind to the height of my window (`Name="MainForm"`) just fine.  But then it is too long.

If I try to bind to a grid in the window (`Name="MainGrid"`) then the ScrollViewer expands to the full length of the listbox (no scrolling).

Obviously I could hard code the height, but then it will not resize with the window.  A feature that I do not want to loose.

Any Ideas?

This is the xaml with the binding set to MainGrid

```
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="WI Assistant" Height="621.25" Width="943.75" Name="MainForm" FontSize="14">
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <DockPanel Margin="266.25,0,455,12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel1">
        <StackPanel>
           <ScrollViewer  Height="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=Height}">
                    <ListBox Name="cboProjects"  FontSize="14" >
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
                   <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem> <ListBoxItem>Test1</ListBoxItem>
               </ListBox>
           </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

(This will run (F5) in [XamlPadx](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it out of the `StackPanel`, because `StackPanel`s grow unrestricted in the direction of their orientation (vertically, in this case). Start with the simplest possible solution:

```
<Window>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl>
            ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Then add complexity as required.

Comment: +1 Using `StackPanel` with single elements tend to cause these questions often.

Comment: Bless you!  I was about to pull my hair out on this one.  By the way, I was using the stackpanel to stack Expanders (more than 1 control).  I simplified my Xaml  before posting.  Now I know I cannot use a ListBox inside an expander inside a stack panel.  Thanks!

Comment: Or really, a ListBox inside a StackPanel (Expanders aside)

Comment: +1 Scrollviewers in Stackpanels as a rule don't work, I tore may a hair out because of this too

Comment: Whoops. I changed my answer slightly to have an `ItemsControl` in the `ScrollViewer` rather than `ListBox`. That's because the template for a `ListBox` already has a `ScrollViewer` in it, so the external `ScrollViewer` is useless.